# Characters found after end of SQL Statement Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

First off I started my code with:

```
            Comm2 = "INSERT INTO [Results]" _
                 & "([ResultsID], [TestID], [Thickness], [SNR], [STD], [M1], [M2], [kVp], [mAs], [TargetFilter])" _
                 & " values('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & Thickness & "', '" & SNR & "', '" & STD & "','" & M1 & "', '" & M2 & "',  '" & kVp & "',  '" & mAs & "',  '" & TargetFilter & "')"

            Comm3 = "INSERT INTO [Test]" _
                 & "([TestID], [Date], [MachineID], [RadiographerID])" _
                 & " values('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & todaysdate & " ', '" & 1 & " ', '" & UserID & " ',)"
```

However this didn't work as the tables are related in the database so had to change them at the same time, so i am currently trying this:

```
            Comm2 = "INSERT INTO [Results] ([ResultsID],[TestID],[Tickness],[SNR],[STD],[M1],[M2],[kVp],[mAs],[TargetFilter]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & Thickness & "', '" & SNR & "', '" & STD & "','" & M1 & "', '" & M2 & "',  '" & kVp & "',  '" & mAs & "',  '" & TargetFilter & "');" _
                & "INSERT INTO [Test] ([TestID], [Date[, [MachineID], [RadiographerID]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CDate(todaysdate) & " ', '" & CInt(MachineID) & "', '" & CStr(UserID) & "')"
            OleDbInsertCommand.Connection = conn
            OleDbInsertCommand.CommandText = Comm2
            adapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand
            adapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And I am getting this error:
https://gyazo.com/36aa32cbfb0f54bbe571f6a9384114e1

```
            Comm2 = "INSERT INTO [Results] ([ResultsID], [TestID], [Thickness], [SNR], [STD], [M1], [M2], [kVp], [mAs],[TargetFilter]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & Thickness & "', '" & SNR & "', '" & STD & "','" & M1 & "', '" & M2 & "',  '" & kVp & "',  '" & mAs & "',  '" & TargetFilter & "')"
            comm3 = " INSERT INTO [Test] ([TestID], [Date], [MachineID], [RadiographerID]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CDate(todaysdate) & " ', '" & CInt(MachineID) & "', '" & CInt(UserID) & "')"

            OleDbInsertCommand.Connection = conn
            OleDbInsertCommand.CommandText = comm3
            adapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand
            adapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            OleDbInsertCommand.CommandText = Comm2
            adapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand
            adapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: More than likely the problem will go away if you use SQL Parameters rather than gluing bits of string together.

Comment: Hey, I just googled "SQL Parameters" and cannot find anything that looks similar, do you have a good link where I can boff up my knowledge of this or have an example of it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx and about 1-2 million Qs here

Comment: Add a break point and copy Comm2 to the clipboard. Then using SSMS, try executing the statement there. It might provide some additional feedback on what's wrong with the statement. Alternatively, post the resulting statement here. I'm sure some sharp SQL guy will spot the problem.

Comment: Parameter queries are good, but the actual problem here ("characters found after ...") is Access will not allow you to combine 2 `INSERT` statements and execute them as a batch.

Comment: When I had them seperatly It said I could not do it as the table that i was changing is related to another table, how can I get past that? Thanks!

Comment: `INSERT` a row with the required value into the "another table" first.  Then the other `INSERT` can succeed because the relationship constraint has been satisfied.

Comment: Your `Results.TestID` is a foreign key to `Test.TestID` and you're enforcing referential integrity such that each `Results.TestID` must exist in `Test`, correct?  If so, `INSERT INTO [Test] ...` and then `INSERT INTO [Results] ...`

Comment: never, only tommied7 online :) Thanks for the fast response, we have got past that error now! but now onto a new one, have you ever seen this? https://gyazo.com/42892656fdf7b0e9c9ddc040a43a4314 I have updated the main thread with the code that i am now using!

Comment: https://gyazo.com/83198fbb0a68da12b1a78afb5619e0c4 this is what my database relationships look like

Comment: Yes, one of your `INSERT`s attempts to add a value into a column which has a unique constraint, and that value is already present in another row of the destination table.  If you know which of the two `INSERT`s triggers that error (do you?), you know where to start looking for the unique constraint (primary key or unique index).

Comment: thankyou very much! I have got it working!!

Answer (score 1):

```
        Comm2 = "INSERT INTO [Results] ([ResultsID], [TestID], [Thickness], [SNR], [STD], [M1], [M2], [kVp], [mAs],[TargetFilter]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & Thickness & "', '" & SNR & "', '" & STD & "','" & M1 & "', '" & M2 & "',  '" & kVp & "',  '" & mAs & "',  '" & TargetFilter & "')"
        comm3 = " INSERT INTO [Test] ([TestID], [Date], [MachineID], [RadiographerID]) VALUES('" & CInt(NewRID) & " ', '" & CDate(todaysdate) & " ', '" & CInt(MachineID) & "', '" & CInt(UserID) & "')"

        OleDbInsertCommand.Connection = conn
        OleDbInsertCommand.CommandText = comm3
        adapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand
        adapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        OleDbInsertCommand.CommandText = Comm2
        adapter2.InsertCommand = OleDbInsertCommand
        adapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: An answer usually tells us why it's an answer.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.